# Testing similarities does not retrieve the expected boolean count?

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, similarity, floating-point-precision, grasshopper

Testing similarity between two sets of decimal numbers (x and y coordinate of pt1 and pt2 located on [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ky3hsn9pv10w4ar/AAB646r7SYy2u0KHwgjg4GRCa)). I do not get the expected count of boolean values (15,682). Could it be a [**decimal to binary conversion**](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) issue? Changing the threshold does not always help, especially with many more numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

x is a sorted list of doubles

```
for i = 1 to x.count-1
if Math.Abs(x(i)-x(i-1))<myThreshold then...
```

Comment: Can you give an example of values that give the wrong result?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on two numbers that should match and aren't ?

Comment: @Jens I have added the two files to the question

Comment: @the_lotus not entirely sure how I could identify the values that don't match.

Comment: If you care about actual equality, why are you checking for a range, rather than equality?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan because actual equality does not work either and I thought a range would help but even that doesn't.

Comment: What steps are needed to get from the files to the sorted list `x`? Ideally, provide a short program that will read the files, produce `x`, and execute the loop showing what is going wrong.

Comment: Is this for Grasshopper the Rhino plugin? Are you specifically interested in comparing numbers or do you have a higher order task that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ben we re trying to find the index of duplicate consecutive points in Grasshopper. There are a lot of them and we don't get the expected count...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I like complicated answers, there's a nice `cull duplicates` feature in Grasshopper. I tested it on 1144 of your values and it returned 865 of them that were unique.

As these are points it's the fastest way to remove the duplicates. On my system it's 46ms vs 1.1s to do the same thing with python.

[image: Simple cull rig]

As you increase the tolerance from 0 to 0.2 the number of unique points drops, but quite abruptly:

[image: graph of number of unique points]

So it seems that you only have identical points. This might be something to do with the way that you've exported the data that you have in dropbox, but as all your numbers are to 6dp I think that you are safe to use this method ans take advantage of all the optimisations that David has built in.

Answer (score 2):

Since floating point numbers have a set number of significant figures (as opposed to fixed point's set number of decimal places) the absolute difference will discriminate poorly between large values and the relative error

```
Math.Abs(x(i)-x(i-1)) / Math.Max(Math.Abs(x(i)), Math.Abs(x(i-1)))
```

should be used instead.
Unfortunately, this tends to exaggerate differences between small values (and breaks down completely for two values equal to zero), so for those the absolute difference is preferable.
You can trade off between them with a normalised difference

```
Math.Abs(x(i)-x(i-1)) / (1.0+Math.Max(Math.Abs(x(i)), Math.Abs(x(i-1))))
```

which tends to the relative difference for values with magnitudes much larger than one and to the absolute difference for values with magnitudes much smaller than one.